# How to make rspec pick up defaults for attributes, set in the schema of a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, migration

When setting a default for a column in a migration, Rails picks this up just fine:

```
def change
  add_column :account, :role, :string, default: 'mother'
  Account.update_all(role: 'mother')
end
```

Accessing this in e.g. rails console works as expected:

```
Account.new.role #=> 'mother'
```

But, for some reason, not in rspec specs:

```
expect(Account.new.role).to equal 'mother' #fail
expect(Account.new.role).to not_be_nil     #fail
```

I can imagine that rspec model specs try to avoid loading the schema and therefore know nothing about the default for an attribute. I am not sure if this is the reason though.

Is there some setting, magic trick or other call that will allow me to test the behaviour of such defaults.

Note: I am aware of the 'after_initialize' trick or even entire gems to set defaults, but this setting of a default in the migration seems the cleanest for me. Still, I'd like to test this.

Comment: Have you run migrations for test environment? either RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load or rake db:test:prepare. RSpec loads whole schema, otherwise you wouldn't be able to create any new instances of models using ActiveRecord

Comment: d'oh. Having worked on a minitest/rails4 project for a while made me too comfortable with Rails managing my test database. migrating the test separately fixes the issue. Could you turn this into an answer so I can accept this?

Comment: done an edit to my reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not keep symbols in the database. Rails automatically convert numbers & symbols in the string column by calling #to_s on them.

If you want to receive symbol for a database column then you should override the method in your model like this:

```
def role
  read_attribute(:role).try(:to_sym)
end
```

**Edit:**

Have you run migrations for test environment? either RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load or rake db:test:prepare. RSpec loads whole schema, otherwise you wouldn't be able to create any new instances of models using ActiveRecord

Comment: You are right, but that is not the actual problem. I'll update my question to point out that the value is not set at all in rspec, but gets set with Account.new anywhere else.